# Appending a dictionary into a dataframe where dict key matches some df row value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and dictionary like the following:

```
df = 
    name    characteristic  value 
    bob     job             doctor 
    bob     age             25
    jim     job             doctor
    jim     age             25
    jim     height          6'

mydict = { 'bob': 10, 'jim': 4 }
```

The dictionary describes a multiplier value for all rows that have a particular name.

I want to count the number of duplicate characteristic and value pairs in this dataframe, but then provide a multiplier value to that count, where the multiplier is the value in my dictionary.

The dataframe I am trying to obtain would look something like this:

```
df = 
    name    characteristic  value     count   multiplier  total
    bob     job             doctor    2       10          20
    bob     age             25        2       10          20
    jim     job             doctor    2       4           8
    jim     age             25        2       4           8
    jim     height          6'        1       4           4
```

I am able to produce the count column, but am totally stuck appending the dictionary into the dataframe.  How could I create the multiplier column in the final dataframe shown above using my original df and dictionary?

Comment: Tags are used to convey what languages or libraries you are referring to. They are not needed in titles.

Answer (score 4):

I've broken down the steps for you:

1. Use `groupby` + `transform` to get counts of values -

   ```
   df['count'] = df.groupby('value').value.transform('count')
   ```
2. Use `pd.Series.map` to map names to multipliers -

   ```
   df['multiplier'] = df['name'].map(mydict)
   ```

   On older versions, you may consider `df['multiplier'] = df['name'].replace(mydict)` instead.
3. Finally, compute the total, this is straightforward.

   ```
   df['total'] = df['count'] * df['multiplier']
   ```

```
df    
  name characteristic   value  count  multiplier  total
0  bob            job  doctor      2          10     20
1  bob            age      25      2          10     20
2  jim            job  doctor      2           4      8
3  jim            age      25      2           4      8
4  jim         height      6'      1           4      4
```

Comment: @jpp If I omit the column accessor, it will replicate the counts for each column in the dataframe (I just need one, I could pick any of them ;) )

Comment: thanks for the help @COLDSPEED. Is there another way to accomplish what map does? I am using an old version of pandas and map is not available... I am stuck using version 0.10 unfortunately have no way around this.

Comment: @bwrabbit See if `df['multiplier'] = df['name'].replace(mydict)` works.

Comment: @bwrabbit that's some ancient pandas there.

Comment: Thanks so much!! yes that does it. :D

Comment: @bwrabbit More recent versions of pandas offer better performance for the same routines. Ask your boss if they can do something about the version.